# How to effective get the max data in sub group and get the min data in among big groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Firstly, I hope to get the max date in each sub-groups.

Group A = action 1 & 2

Group B = action 3 & 4

| actionName | action | actionBy | actiontime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 999 | 1 | Tom | 2022-07-15 09:18:00 |
| 999 | 1 | Tom | 2022-07-15 15:21:00 |
| 999 | 2 | Peter | 2022-07-15 14:06:00 |
| 999 | 2 | Peter | 2022-07-15 14:08:00 |
| 999 | 3 | Sally | 2022-07-15 14:20:00 |
| 999 | 3 | Mary | 2022-07-15 14:22:00 |
| 999 | 4 | Mary | 2022-07-15 14:25:00 |

In this example:

The max time of group A is  "1   |   Tom      |     2022-07-15 15:21:00 "

The max time of group B is  " 4   |   Mary      |     2022-07-15 14:25:00     "

The final answer is  "1   |   Tom      |     2022-07-15 14:25:00 ", which is the minimum data among groups.

I have a method how to get the max date in each group like the following code.

```
with cte1
as (select actionName,
           actiontime,
           actionBy,
           row_number() over (partition by actionName order by actiontime desc) as rn
    from actionDetails
    where action in ( '1', '2' )
    UNION
    select actionName,
           actiontime,
           actionBy,
           row_number() over (partition by actionName order by actiontime desc) as rn
    from actionDetails
    where action in ( '3', '4' )
   )
select *
from cte1
where rn = 1
```

ActionName is not PK. It would get the max data in each group.

Then, I don't know how to use an effective way to get the minimum data between group A and group B. Would you give me some ideas?

I know one of the methods is self join again. However, I think that is not the best solution.

Comment: I am confused. Isn't `id` the unique ID of the table, as its name suggests? Sounds like the table's primary key to me, but that doesn't match your query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes. the id is not the primary key. I updated. Is it necessary to include the primary key to the CTE?

Comment: No, you don't need the ID in your query. Now it looks good.

Comment: On a side note: Better use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` when there are no duplicates to remove. Don't give the DBMS more work than necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can simplify your query by putting the action groups into the partition clause. Use a case expression to get one group for actions 1 and 2 and another for actions 3 and 4.

Then after getting the maximum dates per actionname and action group you want to get the minimum dates of these per actionname. This means you want a second CTE building up on the first one:

```
with max_per_group as
(
  select top(1) with ties
    actionname,
    actiontime,
    actionby
  from actiondetails
  where action in (1, 2, 3, 4)
  order by row_number() 
             over (partition by actionname, case when action <= 2 then 1 else 2 end
                   order by actiontime desc)
)
, min_of_max as
(
  select top(1) with ties
    actionname,
    actiontime,
    actionby
  from max_per_group
  order by row_number() over (partition by actionname order by actiontime)
)
select actionname, actiontime, actionby
from min_of_max
order by actionname;
```

As you see, instead of computing a row number and then have to limit rows based on that in the next query, I limit the rows right away by putting the row numbering into the `ORDER BY` clause and applying `TOP(1) WITH TIES` to get all rows numbered 1. I like this a tad better, because the CTE already produces the rows that I want to work with rather than only marking them in a bigger data set. But that's personal preference I guess.

Discaimer:

In my query I assume that the column action is numeric. If the column is a string instead, because it can hold values that are not numbers, then work with strings:

```
where action in ('1', '2', '3', '4')

partition by actionname, case when action in ('1', '2') then 1 else 2 end
```

If on the other hand the column is a string, but there are only numbers in that column, fix your table instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Only a small change. In min_of_max, I think it should be "order by actiontime asc"

Comment: @Martin TT: Yes, you are right of course. Sorry for the mistake. I've corrected my answer accordingly.